# C array error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, arrays

```
char a[MAX_NR_DIGITS] = {5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 3, 4, 4};
int sizeA = 10;
char n[MAX_NR_DIGITS] = {5, 2, 6};
int sizeN = 3;
```

It returns me twice the error: variable-sized object may not be initialized.
How can i solve this?

Comment: What is `MAX_NR_DIGITS`? Where do you get the errors? Can you please try to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And include the full and complete and unedited error output when building?

Comment: What development environnment do you use ?

Comment: I guess that `MAX_NR_DIGITS` is not a constant. It's only a _guess_ because you don't tell us what `MAX_NR_DIGITS` is

Comment: Obviously it is not an integer constant or the OP wouldn't get that error.

Comment: MAX_NR_DIGITS is 10^8. I have to calculate a^n and the result can have max 10^8 digits. So MAX_NR_DIGITS is a const int .

Answer (score 1):

In case those arrays are declared at local scope and `MAX_NR_DIGITS` is not a compile-time integer constant, C will attempt to create a variable-length array (VLA). This is an array which has its size determined during run-time.

The easiest way to avoid this is, if it was unintentional, is to make sure that `MAX_NR_DIGITS` is a compile-time constant such as `#define MAX_NR_DIGITS 10`.

The reason why the code doesn't work when the array is a VLA, is because initializer lists are only used during compile-time. Therefore the C language has a requirement saying that VLAs cannot be initialized.

For a VLA you can easily get around this by assigning the array a value in run-time instead:

```
memcpy(n,  &(char[3]){5, 2, 6},  3);
```